# Circuit inverts at high frequency and is unity at low frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, transfer-function

Does anyone recognize this op amp setup?

I've figured that at low frequencies C1 is as short circuit, putting the +ve and -ve inputs to \$V_{in}\$ and at high frequencies it will be as open circuit putting +ve and -ve to virtual ground, making it an inverting op amp (unity inverting?).

I have to find the transfer function (and subsequently, bode plots), and my attempts so far haven't quite worked.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmrysU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was wondering if it had a name I could do some research on to understand how to go about it.

Comment: That looks similar to a circuit used to measure the CMRR of an op-amp. Maybe these will help:
https://www.elprocus.com/common-mode-rejection-ratio-cmrr-operational-amplifier/
also
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/aschvun/FAQ/DiffAmp.html

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the similarity to a differential op amp, but there is only one V in so I figured it was coincidental. I'll look into the other.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if that particular circuit actually has a real-world use or if it's just an arbitrary HW circuit. CMRR test circuit should be clsoe enough to get you on your way though.

Comment: Very useful responses from everyone, but John D's was the one that got me going, thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an all-pass filter used to shift phase without affecting the amplitude.

From Wikipedia, [LINK:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pass_filter)

[image]

The transfer function is:

[image]

So the magnitude can be flat, because the pole and zero cancel, but the phase exhibits a shift, I.e. the filter has unity-gain magnitude for all frequencies (until the op-amp runs out of steam). The filter introduces a different delay at each frequency and reaches input-to-output quadrature at ω=1/RC (i.e., phase shift is 90°)

Answer (score 0):

I used one of these to try and change the phase on AM rectifier for a Wheatstone bridge. The circuit ended up not being able to rectify with the precision that I wanted.

It basically changes the phase from 180 to 0 or less (dashed green line) (vout in green is the above circuit and blue is the normal gained op amp).

Depending on where you put the pole you can get different phase results, this is simulated with an ideal op amp, a real op amp will have different phase effects.

[image]

Comment: If it's simulated w/ an ideal op amp, why does the inverting amplifier have a frequency response at all?

Comment: LTSpice says the ideal op-amp says its op-amp still has a one pole.

Comment: The LTSpice "ideal opamp" has a pole at a few Mhz, most likely to help the solver since the more bandwidth you have to simulate (and smaller timestep) the slower it will run.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "Data Slicer".

Used in decoding a Manchester encoded signal.

Op amp's reference level at +ve input follows the average DC level of the incoming Manchester encoded signal

Usually seen like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRHfZK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

or like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbDr2a.png)</sup>

Comment: There is a significant difference in resistor values between the question and your example.

Answer (score 0):

To complement John's [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/424352/110535), assuming an ideal operational amplifier, I obtained the following

$$\frac{V_o (s)}{V_i (s)} = - \left[\frac{s \left(\frac{R_3}{R_1}\right) R_2  C_1 - 1}{s R_2 C_1 + 1} \right]$$

Since \$R_1 = R_2 = R_3 =: R\$, we obtain

$$\frac{V_o (s)}{V_i (s)} = - \left( \frac{s R C_1 - 1}{s R C_1 + 1} \right)$$

which is indeed the transfer function of an [all-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pass_filter).